# How to perform a single sign on between Django app and React JS app?

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a django app and a react js app. The django app has some views, while the react dashboard is the link between the different views of the django app.

**My objective is: When user signs into the react app, the django app should also be logged in and logged out simultaneously.**

For the react app, I am using token authentication, and the token comes from a custom login method I have implemented using django-rest-auth library.

```
api/views.py


class LoginView(views.APIView):

def post(self, request):
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    login(request, user)
    token, created = TokenModel.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key}, status=200)
```

I am calling the token in the react client using axios.

```
export const authLogin = (username, password) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/custom/login/', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    },)
    .then(res => {
        const token = res.data;
        const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600*1000*24*7) //multiplied by 1000 because time is in milliseconds
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
        dispatch(authSuccess(token));
        dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(authFail(err))
    })
}}
```

Here is how my settings.py file looks:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
     'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
     'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
     'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
 ),
 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
     'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
 ),
}

# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'BankScoreCard.User'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'xsrfheadername',
    'xsrfcookiename',
    'content-type',
    'XSRF-TOKEN',
)

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Is there a way, I can set the session ID and the crsftoken coming from the login method of django into my react app, so it works as a single sign on?

Any help would be appreciated.
If question is not clear, please feel free to ask for more details. Thank you.

Comment: Why not try to use JWT token

Answer (score 0):

On successful authentication, Django server will set session information in cookies. All the following requests need to use that session id and the SSO will work automatically. With Axio, the follwing parameter will be required -

```
var instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Additionally settings.py needs to be modified to allow credentials in cross origin requests. Please add the following snippet in the settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I recently created a boilerplate project with similar approach (used fetch in place of axios). 
https://github.com/Parijat29/django-react-boilerplate
Please feel free to poke around it.