# How to implement ADFS SSO having Django as backend and React as frontend?

Tags: reactjs, django, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have registered a app for the django application in Azure Active directory. After the configuration of ADFS to Django app the SSO is working fine. Now I have integrated this Django app with a React app. Now I gotta implement SSO for the same. I need some guidance and direction on how to go forward with this. Please give me an idea to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can implement it as you are using Django as a backend and React as a frontend as far as I can understand. Thus, you can setup authentication such that the front-end react application obtains a JWT token from the Django API server once the API server has successfully authenticated with the Single Sign-on Provider, i.e., ADFS server

•   To do so, login to your ADFS server and click the relying party trust created with the Django app and check all the details regarding the federation properties like data XML link, claims and attributes passing rules, etc. Authenticate to the Django application in Azure AD and check for the successful authentication when the JWT is received in the redirect URI headers. Then, configure your Django app to redirect to the react app with the JWT token in the URI parameters. Once, the JWT token is received by the react app, it will store it and make authenticated API requests as configured. Also, it can refresh the token until the refresh token timeout period expires.

Please find the below link for reference: -

[How to perform a single sign on between Django app and React JS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455549/how-to-perform-a-single-sign-on-between-django-app-and-react-js-app)